# click event fires multiple times

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client template event fires multiple times, from 2 to 23 times depending where I click on the screen.
Why and how to fix it?

```
Template.myT.events({
      'click *:not(canvas)': function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        return;
      });
```

here is the output from the console

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You register the click listener on all elements except canvas elements. When you click on a `<span>` element inside an `<p>` element, you do not only click on the `<span>` element, but also the `<p>` element. This is the reason why the click listener is called multiple times (the event propagates). To prevent that behaviour, use `e.stopPropagation()` in your click handler.

Comment: What if there's some other handler set on an ancestor HTML element? `e.stopPropagation()` would stop it, which probably isn't what you want. A better answer (imo) would be to not set the handlers on so many elements in the first place. `'click *:not(canvas)'` isn't very specific - you should probably use an `id` or `class` attribute.

Comment: @DavidKnipe The code needs to capture the click event outside the canvas , How do you suggest solving it with `id` or `class`?

Comment: @FredJ., Listen for the click event om the body element, and then check if `e.target == theCanvasElement`.